# Проблемы на странице параметров/предпочтений

Tags: дефект, локализация, дизайн

На странице [параметров профиля](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/) присутствуют следующие проблемы:

1. Независимо от состояния галочки выводится один и тот же хинт для двух из четырех чекбоксов:

   [image: Отписаться от почтовых рассылок]

   [image: Включить горячие клавиши]

   Для оставшихся чекбоксов хинты не выводятся вовсе.
2. Следующие сообщения надо писать с прописной буквы:

   - [image: еженедельно]
   - [image: 3 часа]
   - [image: ежедневно]
   - [image: повторная отправка]
3. Отсутствует перевод сообщения при сохранении настроек рассылок:

   > there was a problem unsubscribing from the newsletter - please try again later

   [image: was a problem]
4. При попытке повторно отправить письмо-подтверждение проскакивает текст "unconfirmed":

   [image: unconfirmed]
5. Как можно было увидеть в предыдущих пунктах, присутствуют аж три различных вида сообщений на действия пользователя. Почему бы не сделать это в едином формате?
6. После некоторых манипуляция кнопка перестает реагировать на нажатия мышью, хотя отображается активной (яркой):

   [image: Сохранить настройки]
7. В секции "Новостная рассылка" наблюдается слияние содержимого двух столбцов:

   [image: слияние столбцов]
8. "Параметры" должны стать "Предпочтениями", т.к. они "preferences" по ссылке.